# Apache camel insert data from Postgre to AMQ queue. resulting infinite loop

Tags: xml, postgresql, apache-camel

I want to select all my data in my postgre table and send it to Amq. This is what I have done so far.

```
<route id="insert">
    <from uri="sql:SELECT * FROM mytable" />
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <transform>
        <simple> ${in.body} </simple>
    </transform>
    <log message="${in.body}" />
    <to uri="amqp:queue:testingQueue" />
    <log message="${in.body}" />
</route>
```

This results in infinite loop. The camel route keep selecting the table and sending to queue. I already tried using `controlbus` component, but using control bus only insert 2 data in queue. How can I do that in XML?

Comment: I did not downvote you, but your question is missing key information: the desired behavior. You have attempt something that seems not reach your goal, but never tell us what your goal is. Please supplement your goal into your post by edit.

Comment: okay done. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You goal is "Select all data in particular postgre table and send it to Amqp (do once only)". Under your current setup, you are hard to control the behavior of the route when you put the `sql` component directly in from endpoint.

Instead of putting the `sql` component directly in from endpoint, you should find ways to make sure the route trigger exactly once and then collect DB record from postgre. To do this, the simplest way is to use a `timer` component to trigger route once and a `pollenrich` to trigger DB call once.

```
<from uri="timer://timerId?repeatCount=1" />
    <pollEnrich>
        <constant>sql:SELECT * FROM mytable</constant>
    </pollEnrich>
```

Reference: 
[Camel timer component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html), [Camel pollenrich option](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/content-enricher.html)